# proving conditional independence of a joint probability vector

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, independence

Given a joint probability density function over the random vector $=(1,2,3,4)$ that factorizes as $(1,2,3,4)=(1,4|2)(2,3|1)$

show that the following two statements hold

1. $X_{1} \bot X_{2}$
2. $X_{3} \bot X_{4} | X_{1}, X_{2}$

so far i have come up with the following.

1:
\begin{equation}
p(x_{1},x_{2}) = p(x_{1}) * p(x_{2}) \tag{1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
p(x_{1} | x_{2}) = p(x_{1}) \tag{2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
p(x_{2} | x_{1}) = p(x_{2}) \tag{3}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
p(x_{1},x_{2}) & = \sum_{x_{3}}\sum_{x_{4}}p(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4}) \\
& = \sum_{x_{3}}\sum_{x_{4}}p(x_{1},x_{4} | x_{2}) p(x_{2},x_{3} | x_{1}) \\
& = \sum_{x_{4}}p(x_{1},x_{4} | x_{2}) \sum_{x_{3}}p(x_{2},x_{3} | x_{1}) \\
& = p(x_{1} | x_{2}) p(x_{2} | x_{1}) \\ \\
p(x_{1},x_{2}) & = p(x_{1} | x_{2}) * p(x_{2}) = p(x_{2} | x_{1}) * p(x_{1})
\end{split}
\end{equation}
I am unsure if this is correct, and if it is how i should continue.

2.
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
P(x_{3},x_{4}|x_{1},x_{2}) &= \frac{P(x_3,x_4,x_1,x_2)}{P(x_1,x_2)}\\
& = \frac{P(x_1, x_4 | x_2) P(x_2, x_3 | x_1)}{P(x_1 | x_2)P(x_2 | x_1)}\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Unsure if this correct and how i should continue.

In general i would like to know if i am on the right track with this exercise, and how to finish it.
I am also unsure if i need to prove (1),(2) and (3) or if just one of them suffices.

Comment: part 1) is good, except the last step having the typo. part 2) should follow using result of part 1). The 3 statements are equivalent - any one of them suffices.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, the last line in the derivation should be $p\left(x_1|x_2\right)p\left(x_2|x_1\right)$ since you have integrated $x_4$ out of the expression. So, what you have derived is

\begin{eqnarray*}
p\left(x_1,x_2\right) &=& p\left(x_1|x_2\right)p\left(x_2|x_1\right)\\
&=& \frac{p\left(x_1,x_2\right)^2}{p\left(x_2\right)p\left(x_1\right)}
\end{eqnarray*}

whence $p\left(x_1,x_2\right) = p\left(x_2\right)p\left(x_1\right)$ as required.

For the second part, observe that

\begin{eqnarray*}
p\left(x_1,x_4|x_2\right) &=& p\left(x_4|x_1,x_2\right)p\left(x_1|x_2\right)\\
p\left(x_2,x_3|x_1\right) &=& p\left(x_3|x_1,x_2\right)p\left(x_2|x_1\right)
\end{eqnarray*}

which together with the previous result will give you what you need.